# second ssd that fried, who's to blame?

Tags: ssd, power-supply

I have 2 separate PC's with the same configuration out of which a SSD "**Kingston SA400S37/120G**".

Both SSD failed and I was able to recover the first, but the second is good for RMA.

Should I consider replacing another SSD or the power supply (no-name that came with the case)?

Edit: Power supply code: **SL-500C**

Comment: You are to blame. Kingston are not known for the quality of their SSDs. If its just thecSSDs dying ud say its unlikely to be the PSU.

Comment: Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for